# CSV to Array but remove commas inside double quotes

Tags: javascript, csv, parsing

I am trying to parse the entries in CSV file into an array and it is mostly working. However, some of the entries in the CSV have commas inside of a string which is causing that entry to be mapped improperly, where the split happens on the internal comma rather than the delimiter comma. Here is the code I borrowed mostly from [sebhastian](https://sebhastian.com/javascript-csv-to-array/#:%7E:text=To%20convert%20or%20parse%20CSV,the%20string%20into%20an%20array%20.). And the problematic string is "Case Numbers that begin with 01,91,02,92,03,93". I'm sorry if my description is not complete, and I'm happy to provide any additional information or context y'all might need to help me solve this. Thankful to you for your help in advance.

```
function csvToArray(str, delimiter = ",") {
    
    let headers = str.slice(0, str.indexOf("\n")).split(delimiter);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    headers[i] = headers[i].replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, "_");
    }
    
        const rows = str.slice(str.indexOf('\n') + 1).split('\n');
            
    const arr = rows.map(function (row) {
    const values = row.replace(/['"]+/g, '').split(delimiter);
    const el = headers.reduce(function (object, header, index) {
        object[header] = values[index];
        return object;
    }, {});
    return el;
    });
    
        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: As an exercise it may be interesting to try parsing CSV yourself, but for real-world scenarios I recommend using a library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv. You'd be amazed at how many other edge cases there can be...

Comment: There are multiple implementations of CSV differing slightly in format. [RFC4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) offers a good starting point if you want to write your own decoder. Of note the RFC specifies that double quotes,  commas and line breaks can be included in cell values provided the entire value is double quoted and any double quotes within the value replaced by two double quote characters. Personally I found it necessary to parse the input character by character - splitting the input by delimiter characters (as shown in the link) is not how to parse CSV.

Comment: I had a similar problem sometime ago, there were commas(,) in the data actually so they got split up into different cells. In my case I generated the csv file dynamically with php and later downloaded by the client, so I had much control over the data. All i did was to replace the commas(,) at the csv creation point with its html entity (&comma;). When the client later submit the file, I use javascript to parse it.